# stderr: No ECDSA host key is known for github.com and you have requested strict checking

Tags: ssh, git, aws, github, jenkins

[enter image description here]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo3Al.png)Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- git@github.com:yeni/jenkins-terraform.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: No ECDSA host key is known for github.com and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

i am getting this error when I try to connect GitHub repo with Jenkins. Let me know how to solve it

[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5yic.png)

Answer (score 22):

> ... and you have requested strict checking.

You can check the Jenkins/Git-Host-Key-Verification setting under Global Security...

[image: Jenkins/Git-Host-Key-Verification-Configuration]

Obviously you can workaround it by selecting *No verification* which is not at all recommended though.

In case you want to use *Known hosts file* verification, you can pre-populate the SSH keys for each server, using the below command (on Linux)...

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You have to do that on the user-account that Jenkins is running with.

There is this similar [StackOverflow thread "Jenkins Host key verification failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed), where other solutions are mentioned, alongside the above.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in [StackOverflow thread "Jenkins Host key verification failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed) don't forget to populate the **jenkins** user's `known_hosts` file !

Login before any add to the `known_hosts` using :

```
sudo su - jenkins
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the previous answer.

Comment: my bad, this was just to don't forget (as I did at the first place) to update the jenkins'know_hosts file and not the one of the current user used to log into the VM

Comment: Do you mean "`known_hosts`"?  I suspect so.

Comment: Yes thx @Mr.LanceESloan