# I am facing issue while configuring GitHub ssh key to Jenkins server for ci?

Tags: ssh, github, jenkins

I am facing an issue while configuring SSH Key to Jenkins for GitHub to Jenkins CI. I created an SSH key using this CMD inside of the .ssh directory **ssh-keygen** I copied the private key and pasted it to the Jenkins credentials side using SSH Key, Then I copied the public key and pasted to GitHub SSH key side. Then it showed this error.

```
stderr: No ED25519 host key is known for github.com and you have requested strict checking.
```

[image: Reference Img]

Comment: see this question stderr: No ECDSA host key is known for github.com and you have requested strict checking (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427446/stderr-no-ecdsa-host-key-is-known-for-github-com-and-you-have-requested-strict)